# Clipping a binary number to required length C/C++

Tags: python, c

I have written a short function to convert an input decimal number to a binary output. However, at a much higher level of the code, the end user should toggle an option as to whether or not they desire a 5B or 10B value. For the sake of some other low level maths, I have to clip the data here.

So I need some help figuring out how to clip the output to a desired length and stuff the required number of leading zeros.

The incomplete C code:

```
long dec2bin(int x_dec,int res)
{
    long x_bin = 0;
    int x_bin_len;
    int x_rem, i = 1;
    while (x_dec != 0)
    {
        x_rem = x_dec % 2;
        x_dec /= 2;
        x_bin += x_rem * i;
        i *= 10;
    }
    return x_bin;
}
```

I had completed a working proof of concept using python. The end application however, requires I write this in C.

The working python script:

```
def dec2bin(x_dec,x_res):
    x_bin = bin(x_dec)[2:]                      #Convert to Binary (Remove 0B Prefix)
    x_len = len(x_bin)                          
    if x_len < x_res:                           #If Smaller than desired resolution
        x_bin = '0' * (x_res-x_len) + x_bin     #Stuff with leading 0s
    if x_len > x_res:                           #If larger than desired resolution
        x_bin = x_bin[x_len-x_res:x_len]        #Display desired no. LSBs
    return x_bin
```

I'm sure this has been done before, Indeed, my python script proves it should be relatively straightforward, but I'm not as experienced with C.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

- Mark.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the C++ tag.  You are comparing C and Python.  The C++ language is different than C.  For example, in C++ you can pass by reference and overload functions and operators.

Comment: I highly recommend using pen or pencil and paper and *walking through* your C code.  You should be able to identify a good place to "clip the bits".

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking .. what's 5B vs 10B? All numbers in your computer are stored in binary. Are you asking for a character string that shows the bits padded with leading 0s? Does 5B mean you want to save only the 5 least significant bits of a number and clear the rest?

Comment: So you want to store such value in `x_bin`, that when printed as decimal, it has only 0 and 1 digits, representing bits? That's... quaint.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews. I could have easily used C++ without making too many alterations to the larger bod of code. As it stands someone else provided a function to almost do what I intended, just needs a few tweaks. Usually I don't mind working through problems with pen and paper, but was pressed for time so had to get other stuff working. Apprecite the insight and feedback though.

Comment: Note that `long` does not have a way to specify number of digits. 1 is 01 is 001 is 0001 is 00001 is 000001, they are all the same long value (note that 0 prefix in C source code actually means it's an octal number, btw, so don't write those leading zeroes in code unless you want an octal literal). ***Do you require the leading zeores?***

Comment: @Hyde Yeah, I get that is an unusual practice however, the embedded system in question deals with data transmission. Passing 5 or 10 bit buffers is a hardware limitation, not sure using larger character buffers would work. Although I'm aware this makes the leading zeros a whole new headache...

Comment: The leading zeros are needed for some bitwise operations later in the code. I think If I keep as much of the binary data as characters throughout the main body of code, then figure a way to either transmit leading zeros, or perhaps interoperate the lack thereof on the receiving end... Okay, I think I know how I might do this.  P.S. I wasn't aware that the 0 prefix would cause the data to be interoperated as an octal, that would be counter productive, good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As @yano suggested, I think you have to return an ascii string to the caller, rather than a long. Below's the short function I wrote for my own purposes, for any base...

```
char *itoa ( int i, int base, int ndigits ) {
  static char a[999], digits[99] = /* up to base 65 */
    "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  int n=ndigits;
  memset(a,'0',ndigits);  a[ndigits]='\000';
  while ( --n >= 0) {
    a[n] = digits[i%base];
    if ( (i/=base) < 1 ) break; }
  return ( a );
  } /* --- end-of-function itoa() --- */
```

Comment: Initial test of this function has proved useful, here are some tweaks I'll need to implement to work in the larger body of my code, but I appreciate the help :)